# SATA drivers install on MSI motherboard

Tags: windows-10, drivers, motherboard, sata

I'm running Windows 10 x64 on a MSI B450M MORTAR MAX motherboard with a Crucial MX500 SSD 2TB drive.
On the [support page](https://fr.msi.com/Motherboard/support/B450M-MORTAR-MAX#down-driver&Win10%2064), I can see that there is a "AM4 RAID Driver 9.2.0.127", placed into a "On-Board PIDE/SATA Drivers" section.

Do I have to install these drivers if I don't have any RAID configuration, and don't plan to have one ? If yes, why ?

Next, the release note says that "After installation of setup.exe the user may need to refresh the desktop icons." But there is no setup.exe in the donwloaded file. How are these drivers supposed to be installed ?

I'm asking this question here because I've already asked many other technical questions to the MSI support about their motherboards, and their answers are always just random, or false, or opposite to the real answer, ... and I cannot trust them anymore.

Do anyone familiar with this subject and that know what is the goal of the files contained within the archive can help me with this ?

Comment: "Do I have to install these drivers if I don't have any RAID configuration" No you don't. The files in the archive are used after windows is installed, they are used by device manager to get the drivers installed manually by you.

Comment: @Moab:Hello, I don't understand your answer. Yes, these are drivers, and of course they are to be installed manually after Windows is installed. But that does not say when they have to be installed or not. I mean, if I download a GeForce driver, that's the exact same thing, but I only have to install them if I have a GeForce graphic card. Here, nothing says in the package when these drivers need to be installed. The filename talks about RAID, the section in wich they reside talks about SATA. And you have to deal with this all alone... Are they needed for SATA drives without RAID... ?

Comment: " Are they needed for SATA drives without RAID" No, only if you want to use raid.

Comment: @Moab: Could you please post you last comment as an answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Are they needed for SATA drives without RAID"

No, only if you want to use raid